# How to require different text lengths based on input in another cell

Tags: excel, validation, multiple-conditions

Using Excel Data Validation,
I need to reference Input in Cell D12 to determine text length in Cell G12
D12 & G12 are formatted as text to allow for input of leading zeroes
D12 requires a 3 character response
If the input in D12 is between 265 & 278 or 299 I want Cell G12 to require 6 digits, if it is any other non-blank value, I need Cell G12 to require 3 digits.

I have tried these solutions in Data Validation

---

=OR(AND(OR($D12=266,$D12=267,$D12=268,$D12=269,$D12=270,$D12=271,$D12=272,$D12=273,$D12=274,$D12=275,$D12=276,$D12=277,$D12=299),LEN($G12)=6),LEN($G12)=3)

---

=if(OR(AND(D12=299),AND(D12>265,D12<279)),LEN(G12)=6,LEN(G12)=3))

I need for my error messages to return the following.

If D12 = any of those listed above and G12 does not have 6 digits I need to return "Fund requires area-sub area coding in this format 000000"
If D12 = anything else and G12 does not have 3 digits I need to return "This fund does not have a sub area. Please enter the 3 digit area only"

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not sure you can have data validation with two different error messages. VBA should work, if that's an option.

Comment: I could combine the messages if necessary.  I don't know how to accomplish the data requirement in either validation, or in VBA.  Any help is much appreciated.